# Is class binding an attribute binding or a property binding?

Tags: angular

I know the difference between attributes and properties. I know class is an HTML tag attribute and a DOM node has a property named className or classList.

In angular2, why class binding(and style binding) is special? is it an attribute binding or a property binding? Or just neither?

Comment: While this may not directly answer your question, the A2 docs has a pretty good explanation on the topic: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#other-bindings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[style.xxx]="..."` and `[class.xxx]="..."` are neither. It is special Angular syntax.

`[ngClass]="..."` and `[ngStyle]="..."` are property bindings. `NgClass` and `NgStyle` are directives with `@Input() ngClass;` and `@Input() ngStyle;` which creates properties.